# VsVim 2022 keybindings not being applied

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vsvim

I'm trying to get **VsVim** for **Visual Studio 2022** working, and have found that nothing changes--as if the extension was never installed; there are no error dialogs or logs.

I have tried restarting Visual Studio, restarting the computer itself, and uninstalling and reinstalling the extension multiple times.

The result is always the same:

- The keyboard bindings have not changed.
- The VsVim output is blank.
- The keyboard page ( *Options > VsVim > Keyboard* ) states "An error occurred loading this property page".

[image]

Comment: Are you using this version https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaredParMSFT.VsVim2022Preview&ssr=false#overview ? If so then it might be better to raise this issue with the extension creator.